# Manipulating properties of objects: assigning a method to a property

Tags: javascript

Why does this return null

```
    var char = str.charAt(i);
    char.isSpace = /\s/.test(char);
    return char.isSpace;
```

While this returns a valid boolean?

```
    var char = str.charAt(i);
    var isSpace = /\s/.test(char);
    return isSpace;
```

Comment: What is `str` defined as?

Comment: show full function definition

Comment: @millerbr `str` is defined as a string
@RomanPerekhrest I don't see why that's relevant to answering a theoretical question about assigning methods to object properties.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry dude, i tried. StackOverflow said too much code, not enough details. Gonna have to just stayed focused on the question, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var char = str.charAt(i);
// after this assignment char is a string (but not String Object)
char.isSpace = /\s/.test(char);
// 1. you can't assign a property to char, it's not an Object
// 2. if you could, you weren't assigning a method to char, but a value
return char.isSpace;
// so, char.isSpace is undefined
```

You *can* assign a method to `String` (static) or `String.prototype`, e.q.:

```
String.isWhitespace = function (str) {return /\s/g.test(str);}
var char = str.charAt(i);
String.isWhitespace(char); //=> true/false

String.prototype.isWhitespace = function () {return /\s/g.test(str);}
var char = str.charAt(i);
char.isWhitespace(); //=> true/false
```

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you so much! Wow!

Comment: one question: why the `g` after `/\/s/` ?

Comment: You can/may want to use it for strings too: `'I\ncontain\nwhitespace\treally!'.isWhitespace(); //=> true`. In that case `containsWhitespace` would be a better method-name ;)